# Spring Boot : APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Tags: spring-boot

Wanted to learn Spring Boot with some sample examples.. Created a simple project without any additional changes. Just started the spring boot application for successfully start then will add more functionality. But server is not getting started.Below is server log : Server is not getting started. Used JDK  8 and spring boot 4.0 version.

```
o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2671 ms
concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase   : Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1008) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:226) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:259) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:197) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:311) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:164) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552) [spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.discovery.SpringEcartServiceApplication.main(SpringEcartServiceApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:94) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:61) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(PipeImpl.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:50) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Pipe.java:155) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:127) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(WindowsSelectorProvider.java:44) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Selector.java:227) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector(NioSelectorPool.java:54) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.close(NioSelectorPool.java:109) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:338) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1108) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:568) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1005) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:189) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer$LoopbackConnector.run(PipeImpl.java:127) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:76) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    ... 29 common frames omitted

2019-04-27 10:40:09.166  INFO 6032 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-04-27 10:40:09.232  INFO 6032 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.


***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************    
The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be mis-configured.
```

Comment: Exception says it all `The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be mis-configured.`

Comment: Had change the default port to multiple times but getting same kind of Exception. However there was no connector configuration made externally. If it needs to configure then please  guide where to configure as tomcat is inbuilt with spring boot and we dont do any tomcat related changes. Thanks

Comment: You might be having another application running on 8080 port. Try changing the port to something else by changing `server.port` property in `application.properties` file

Comment: Changed the port to server.port=8181 then 8190 then 9100 etc.. but getting same exception.

Comment: You might want to check your firewall settings "Unable to establish loopback connection; Caused by: Connection timed out"... seems to me that application is unable to connect to localhost (loopback connection). Also, are you running the application from inside an IDE ? If yes, try to find an answer for this error with the IDE name.

Comment: Hi Uttam, I am using STS, I am having the same issue. I changed server different `server.port=9090`, or `8081`... but I am still getting the same exception. Any luck solving this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Provided possible way to solve and identify issue in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65406134/spring-boot-application-is-not-starting/77964326#77964326