# Spring boot application is not starting

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

My spring boot application is not able to start. I am unable to find the root cause of that. I guess Hikari pool may create the issue for that. Below is the log. Any help will be appreciated.

```
{"timestamp": "12/22/2020 14:48:58:0354", "class": "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator", "file": "HikariPool.java", "level" : "DEBUG", "line_number" : "728", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@b986d4e, "method": "call", "thread_name": "HikariPool-1 connection adder"},
{"timestamp": "12/22/2020 14:48:58:0368", "class": "com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource", "file": "HikariDataSource.java", "level" : " INFO", "line_number" : "350", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated..., "method": "close", "thread_name": "restartedMain"},
{"timestamp": "12/22/2020 14:48:58:0369", "class": "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool", "file": "HikariPool.java", "level" : "DEBUG", "line_number" : "421", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": HikariPool-1 - Before shutdown stats (total=6, active=0, idle=6, waiting=0), "method": "logPoolState", "thread_name": "restartedMain"},
{"timestamp": "12/22/2020 14:48:58:0375", "class": "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase", "file": "PoolBase.java", "level" : "DEBUG", "line_number" : "134", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@25f592ec: (connection evicted), "method": "quietlyCloseConnection", "thread_name": "HikariPool-1 connection closer"},
{"timestamp": "12/22/2020 14:48:58:0378", "class": "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase", "file": "PoolBase.java", "level" : "DEBUG", "line_number" : "134", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@36e8820f: (connection evicted), "method": "quietlyCloseConnection", "thread_name": "HikariPool-1 connection closer"},
{"timestamp": "12/22/2020 14:48:58:0379", "class": "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase", "file": "PoolBase.java", "level" : "DEBUG", "line_number" : "134", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@382f7aa2: (connection evicted), "method": "quietlyCloseConnection", "thread_name": "HikariPool-1 connection closer"},
{"timestamp": "12/22/2020 14:48:58:0380", "class": "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase", "file": "PoolBase.java", "level" : "DEBUG", "line_number" : "134", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@3c10e97f: (connection evicted), "method": "quietlyCloseConnection", "thread_name": "HikariPool-1 connection closer"},
{"timestamp": "12/22/2020 14:48:58:0380", "class": "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase", "file": "PoolBase.java", "level" : "DEBUG", "line_number" : "134", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@79127099: (connection evicted), "method": "quietlyCloseConnection", "thread_name": "HikariPool-1 connection closer"},
{"timestamp": "12/22/2020 14:48:58:0381", "class": "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase", "file": "PoolBase.java", "level" : "DEBUG", "line_number" : "134", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@b986d4e: (connection evicted), "method": "quietlyCloseConnection", "thread_name": "HikariPool-1 connection closer"},
{"timestamp": "12/22/2020 14:48:58:0388", "class": "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator", "file": "HikariPool.java", "level" : "DEBUG", "line_number" : "728", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@48a1ecf5, "method": "call", "thread_name": "HikariPool-1 connection adder"},
{"timestamp": "12/22/2020 14:48:58:0388", "class": "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase", "file": "PoolBase.java", "level" : "DEBUG", "line_number" : "134", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@48a1ecf5: (connection evicted), "method": "quietlyCloseConnection", "thread_name": "HikariPool-1 connection closer"},
{"timestamp": "12/22/2020 14:48:58:0389", "class": "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool", "file": "HikariPool.java", "level" : "DEBUG", "line_number" : "421", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": HikariPool-1 - After shutdown stats (total=0, active=0, idle=0, waiting=0), "method": "logPoolState", "thread_name": "restartedMain"},
{"timestamp": "12/22/2020 14:48:58:0389", "class": "com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource", "file": "HikariDataSource.java", "level" : " INFO", "line_number" : "352", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed., "method": "close", "thread_name": "restartedMain"},
{"timestamp": "12/22/2020 14:48:58:0390", "class": "org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager", "file": "PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java", "level" : "DEBUG", "line_number" : "411", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": Connection manager is shutting down, "method": "shutdown", "thread_name": "restartedMain"},
{"timestamp": "12/22/2020 14:48:58:0390", "class": "com.amazonaws.http.IdleConnectionReaper", "file": "IdleConnectionReaper.java", "level" : "DEBUG", "line_number" : "190", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": Reaper thread: , "method": "run", "thread_name": "java-sdk-http-connection-reaper"},
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.IdleConnectionReaper.run(IdleConnectionReaper.java:188) [aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.908.jar:?]
IdleConnectionReaper.java:188
{"timestamp": "12/22/2020 14:48:58:0390", "class": "com.amazonaws.http.IdleConnectionReaper", "file": "IdleConnectionReaper.java", "level" : "DEBUG", "line_number" : "194", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": Shutting down reaper thread., "method": "run", "thread_name": "java-sdk-http-connection-reaper"},
{"timestamp": "12/22/2020 14:48:58:0390", "class": "org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection", "file": "LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection.java", "level" : "DEBUG", "line_number" : "79", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": http-outgoing-0: Close connection, "method": "close", "thread_name": "restartedMain"},
{"timestamp": "12/22/2020 14:48:58:0391", "class": "com.amazonaws.internal.SdkSSLSocket", "file": "SdkSSLSocket.java", "level" : "DEBUG", "line_number" : "76", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": shutting down output of xxx, "method": "shutdownOutput", "thread_name": "restartedMain"},
{"timestamp": "12/22/2020 14:48:58:0391", "class": "com.amazonaws.internal.SdkSSLSocket", "file": "SdkSSLSocket.java", "level" : "DEBUG", "line_number" : "69", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": shutting down input of xxx, "method": "shutdownInput", "thread_name": "restartedMain"},
{"timestamp": "12/22/2020 14:48:58:0391", "class": "com.amazonaws.internal.SdkSSLSocket", "file": "SdkSSLSocket.java", "level" : "DEBUG", "line_number" : "62", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": closing xxx, "method": "close", "thread_name": "restartedMain"},
{"timestamp": "12/22/2020 14:48:58:0391", "class": "org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager", "file": "PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java", "level" : "DEBUG", "line_number" : "434", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": Connection manager shut down, "method": "shutdown", "thread_name": "restartedMain"},
{"timestamp": "12/22/2020 14:48:58:0395", "class": "org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog", "file": "DirectJDKLog.java", "level" : " INFO", "line_number" : "173", "url": "", "ip_address": "", "server_trace_id":"", "message": Stopping service [Tomcat], "method": "log", "thread_name": "restartedMain"},
```

Here is a complete maven configuration of my project which I have used. I am using spring boot 2.4.3 with spring data jpa

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>xxx</groupId>
  <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>xxxn</name>
  <description>Application of xxx</description>

  <properties>
    <java.version>14</java.version>
    <java.aws.version>1.11.908</java.aws.version>

    <sonar.projectKey>xxxx</sonar.projectKey>
    <sonar.organization>xxx</sonar.organization>
    <sonar.host.url>xxx</sonar.host.url>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
      <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AWS related dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager</artifactId>
      <version>${java.aws.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-bus</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
      <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!--rest-assured dependency -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
      <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
      <version>3.10.3</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.23</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
          <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
          <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
      <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.atlassian.connect</groupId>
      <artifactId>atlassian-connect-spring-boot-jwt</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
      <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
      <version>3.10.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.ai.redpen.RedpenApplication</mainClass>
          <source>14</source>
          <target>14</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/misc/swagger/swagger.yaml</inputSpec>
              <language>spring</language>
              <library>spring-boot</library>
              <apiPackage>com.ai.redpen.controller</apiPackage>
              <modelPackage>com.ai.redpen.dto</modelPackage>
              <generateApis>true</generateApis>
              <generateModels>true</generateModels>
              <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
              <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
              <skipOverwrite>false</skipOverwrite>
              <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
              <configOptions>
                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                <java8>false</java8>
                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
              </configOptions>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
          <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
              <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
              <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
              <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            </path>
          </annotationProcessorPaths>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Post your pom.xml file content

Comment: related (with no answer) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63242758/aws-interruptedexception-sleep-interrupted-com-amazonaws-http-idleconnectionrea

Comment: @dm_rt I have added a pom file can please check and give me some solution on it.

Comment: @user7294900, it's an unanswered question.

Comment: Please add the startup logs, also how do you know it doesn't start? The logging shows it has started. Do you have also regular logging as I find this JSON stuff unreadable.

Comment: @M.Deinum, yes you are right it's up successful but during the process, it stops. If I share a complete log it might not allow me to upload that much of a log. Do you have any other workaround? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Majority of problems can be solved with debugging if they are not compilation issue.

Below is a QUICK HACK with debugging (NOT direct solution):

For Spring - put debug point in CATCH block of function in SpringApplication.class

```
public ConfigurableApplicationContext run(String... args)
```

Majority of the problems will be known by this including:

- Bean initialization
- Invalid Properties for Spring

Ideal way to handle such scenarios is to start logging for each spring modules in logback.xml or your app related log file which tells spring to start logging.

How to enable remote debugging for spring boot:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"
```

OR

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005 -jar application.jar
```